# Where do I find the project ID for the GitLab API?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I use GitLab on their servers. I would like to download my latest built artifacts (build via GitLab CI) via the API like this:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/1/builds/8/artifacts"
```

Where do I find this project ID? Or is this way of using the API not intended for hosted GitLab projects?

Comment: I created an issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28342

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can query for your owned projects:

```
curl -XGET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?owned=true"
```

You will receive JSON with each owned project:

```
[
  {
    "id":48,
    "description":"",
    "default_branch":"master",
    "tag_list":[
...
```

---

You are also able to get the project ID from the triggers configuration in your project which already has some sample code with your ID.

From the Triggers page:

```
curl -X POST \
     -F token=TOKEN \
     -F ref=REF_NAME \
     https://<GitLab Installation>/api/v3/projects/<ProjectID>/trigger/builds
```

Comment: great thx - helps a lot. Small note: I think -header should be --header.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore. See answer by @Bernát. You can see the project ID on the project settings page.

Comment: @AtesGoral I am not seeing the project ID in the project settings page. Where is it supposed to be?

Comment: @Fairy Which version of GitLab are you using?

Comment: @AtesGoral  8.15.4

Comment: @Fairy Go to Settings -> CI/CD Pipelines. On the Triggers section, the URL examples contain the project ID. e.g. "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/xxxxxx/trigger/builds"

Comment: v3_to_v4.md, "/api/v4/projects?owned=true"

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects

Answer (score 92):

I just found out an even easier way to get the project id: just see the HTML content of the gitlab page hosting your project. There is an input with a field called project_id, e.g:

```
<input type="hidden" name="project_id" id="project_id" value="335" />
```

Comment: Great answer. Despite not guaranteed to work since does not use any API, it is quite possible this approach will remain working indefinitely

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see it right away but was able to print it to the console with a little js: `document.getElementById('project_id').value`

Answer (score 92):

The latest version of GitLab `11.4` at the time of this writing now puts the **Project ID** at the top of the frontpage of your repository.

#### Screenshot:

[image: GitLab Project Front Page]

Comment: Worth noting, you can click to copy the ID to your clipboard

Comment: That's not very useful when the project path needs to be translated to its ID dynamically for automation purposes.

Answer (score 51):

On the Edit Project page there is a Project ID field in the top right corner.

(You can also see the ID on the CI/CD pipelines page, in the exameple code of the Triggers section.)

In older versions, you can see it on the Triggers page, in the URLs of the example code.

Comment: I cannot see this? What gitlab version?

Comment: In the version which is running on Gitlab.com... i don't know exactly, but not long ago, maybe since January 2017. In older versions you can find it in the example code on the Triggers page.

Comment: Goto `Settings > General`

Answer (score 35):

As mentioned [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28342#note_23852124), all the project scoped APIs expect either an ID or the project path (URL encoded).
So just use https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/gitlab-org%2Fgitlab-foss directly when you want to interact with a project.

Comment: +1 important point is that `NAMESPACE/PROJECT_NAME` mentioned after `/api/v4/projects/` must be URL encoded. That means `/` needs to be replaced with `%2F` 
For example: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/gitlab-org%2Fgitlab-ce

Comment: This example is 404 for me.

Answer (score 26):

Enter the project.

On the Left Hand menu click Settings -> General -> Expand General Settings

It has a label Project ID  and is next to the project name.

This is on version GitLab 10.2

Answer (score 16):

Provide the solution that actually solve the problem **the api of getting the project id for specific gitlab project**

```
curl -XGET -H "Content-Type: application/json" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" http://<YOUR-GITLAB-SERVER>/api/v3/projects/<YOUR-NAMESPACE>%2F<YOUR-PROJECT-NAME> | python -mjson.tool
```

Or maybe you just want the project id:

```
curl -XGET -H "Content-Type: application/json" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" http://<YOUR-GITLAB-SERVER>/api/v3/projects/<YOUR-NAMESPACE>%2F<YOUR-PROJECT-NAME> | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["id"])'
```

Note that **the repo url(namespace/repo name) is encoded**.

Comment: In case you are using gitlab.com the namespace would be your username.

Comment: wouldn't the namespace be the owner of the project you are trying to get the project id for, rather than always your own username?

Comment: And the one based on jq: `curl -s -XGET -H "Content-Type: application/json" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" http://<YOUR-GITLAB-SERVER>/api/v3/projects/<YOUR-NAMESPACE>%2F<YOUR-PROJECT-NAME> | jq '.id`

Comment: Thanks! works also with API v4

Answer (score 9):

If you know your project name, you can get the project id by using the following API:

```
curl --header "Private-Token: <your_token>" -X GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?search=<exact_project_name>
```

This will return a JSON that includes the id:

```
[
  {
     "id":<project id>, ...
  }
]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can view it under the repository name

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record, if someone else has the need to download artifacts from gitlab.com created via gitlab-ci

1. Create a private token within your browser
2. Get the project id via `curl -XGET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: YOUR_AD_HERE?" "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/owned"`
3. Download the last artifact from your master branch created via a gitlab-ci step called release `curl -XGET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: YOUR_AD_HERE?" -o myapp.jar "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/4711/builds/artifacts/master/download?job=release"`

I am very impressed about the beauty of gitlab.

Comment: v3 is no longer available. The URL is now: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/PATH_TO_FILE?job=JOB`

Answer (score 5):

In new GitLab version you must click settings in right side Project page and copy Project ID[image]

Comment: To be clear, you need to click the 3 vertical dots to get that to pop up. This works even if you don't have permission to see the "Settings" page of the repo.

Answer (score 4):

You can query projects with search attribute e.g:

http://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects?private_token=xxx&search=myprojectname

Answer (score 4):

As of Gitlab API v4, the following API returns all projects that you own:

```
curl --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_token>' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?owned=true'
```

The response contains project `id`. Gitlab access tokens can be created from this page- https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens

Answer (score 2):

No answer suits generic needs, the most similar is intended only for the gitlab site, not specific sites. This can be used to find the **ID** of the project **streamer** in the Gitlab server *my-server.com*, for example:

```
$ curl --silent --header 'Authorization: Bearer MY-TOKEN-XXXX' \
     'https://my-server.com/api/v4/projects?per_page=100&simple=true'| \
     jq -rc '.[]|select(.name|ascii_downcase|startswith("streamer"))'| \
     jq .id

168
```

Remark that

- this gives only the first 100 projects, if you have more, you should request the pages that follow (&page=2, 3, ...) or run a different API (e.g. groups/:id/projects).
- jq is quite flexible. Here we're just filtering a project, you can do multiple things with it.

Comment: definitely better answer!

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no way to retrieve only the Project ID using the gitlab api. Instead, retrieve all the owner's projects and loop through them until you find the matching project, then return the ID. I wrote a script to get the project ID:

```
#!/bin/bash

projectName="$1"
namespace="$2"
default=$(sudo cat .namespace)
namespace="${namespace:-$default}"
json=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $(sudo cat .token)" -X GET 
'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?owned=true' 2>/dev/null)
id=0
idMatch=0
pathWithNamespaceMatch=0
rowToMatch="\"$(echo "$namespace/$projectName" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')\","
for row in $(echo "${json}" | jq -r '.'); do
    [[ $idMatch -eq 1 ]] && { idMatch=0; id=${row::-1}; }
    [[ $pathWithNamespaceMatch -eq 1 ]] && { pathWithNamespaceMatch=0; [[ "$row" == "$rowToMatch" ]] && { echo "$id"; return 0; } }
    [[ ${row} == "\"path_with_namespace\":" ]] && pathWithNamespaceMatch=1
    [[ ${row} == "\"id\":" ]] && idMatch=1
done
echo 'Error! Could not retrieve projectID.'
return 1
```

It expects the default namespace to be stored in a file `.namespace` and the private token to be stored in a file `.token`. For increased security, its best to run `chmod 000 .token; chmod 000 .namespace; chown root .namespace; chown root .token`

Answer (score 0):

If your project name is unique, it is  handy to follow the answer by shunya, search by name, refer API [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#search-for-projects-by-name).

If you have stronger access token and the Gitlab contains a few same name projects within different groups, then search within group is more convenient. API doc [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/search.html#group-search-api). e.g.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" -X GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/<group_id>/search?scope=projects&search=<project_name>
```

The group ID can be found from the **Settings** page under the group domain.

And to fetch the project id from the output, you can do:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" -X GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/<group_id>/search?scope=projects&search=<project_name> | jq '[0].id'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get id from all projects, use:

```
curl --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?owned=true' > curloutput
grep -oPz 'name\":\".*?\"|{\"id\":[0-9]+' curloutput | sed 's/{\"/\n/g' | sed 's/name//g' |sed 's/id\"://g' |sed 's/\"//g'  | sort -u -n
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Specific to question, but somehow reached here, might help others
I used chrome to get a project ID

1. Go to the desired project example gitlab.com/username/project1
2. Inspect network tab
3. see the first garphql request in network tab [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can **search** for the **project path**

```
curl -s  'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?search=my/path/to/my/project&search_namespaces=true' --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" |python -mjson.tool |grep \"id\"
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html

Which will only match your project and will not find other unnecessary projects

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method is to pull from the CI/CD pipeline so on build it dynamically assigns the project id.

Simply assign a variable in your code to = `CI_PROJECT_ID`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option to find the `project-id`:

[image: Find the project-id.]

If this option is not available, you can search it on the source page:

1. Right-click the main GitLab page of your project
2. Select "View Page Source" (`Ctrl + U` in Chrome)
3. Search for:

```
Project ID:
```

There you go.