# HOW to check id of project in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I want to use GitLab API to get the contents of my project. The URL is like this:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path?private-token=xxxxx
```

I have already created the private token, but I can not find my project's ID.

Looking for reply!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where do I find the project id for the gitlab api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559689/where-do-i-find-the-project-id-for-the-gitlab-api)

Answer (score 3):

Since GitLab 11.2 (August 22nd, 2018), it is easier to check out one's project ID, thanks to [**Tuğçe Nur Taş**](https://gitlab.com/nuritnt).

See "[**Show project ID on project overview**](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/08/22/gitlab-11-2-released/#show-project-id-on-project-overview)":

> GitLab projects are associated with an auto-generated, unique project ID upon creation. This information is available in the General project settings and via our API.
>
> With this release, **we have added the project ID to the project overview page**, so that users without Maintainer permissions also have access to this ID when needed.

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/11_2/project-id-on-overview.png]

- [See documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/),
- [see issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/46342),
- [see merge-request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/20305).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the project's ID, inserting the project path which should be URL encoded.

Example:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/[project path URL encoded]
```