# Get the `id` of gitlab project via gitlab api or gitlab-cli

Tags: git, curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is there any way to get an `id` of the project via GitLab API .

I created a project using GitLab API providing the project name -

`curl -kX POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/my_app&visibility=internal`

It returns expected result with project information like `links`, `id`, `user`, `namespace` etc.
Now I want to create `issue` or create a `branch`. I need the project `id` now.
So how can I retrieve the `id` of my project `my_app`. (Not from UI).

I didn't find any API query that I can create `issue` or `branch` without using project `id`.

I always need `id` [Issues API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#new-issue)

`POST /projects/:id/issues`

As well I didn't find any API query that I can retrieve the `id` using the project `name`

Only thing I can use by Search API and use `project name`
`curl -kX GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/search?scope=projects&search=my_app`

But it provides whole lot of information. I only need to retrieve `project id`. No idea how to get the project `id`?

There is [python-gitlab](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab) lib by which I can do, similar stuff like using `curl`.

- Get projects ( gives most recent 20 projects' `name` and `id` in `yaml` format)

  - `gitlab project list`
- Create project

  - `gitlab -o yaml project create --name "my_app_cli" --visibility "internal"`
  - Create Issue of a project
  - `gitlab -o yaml project create-issue --id ID` Here also I need to provide `id`.

But in this library also, there is no option to retrieve project `id`. 
Same as the API, to create any branch, issue etc, I need to use `id` of the created project. I don't want to put manually the `id` in the `api` or while using `cli`

Is there any workaround to get the id via `api` or `cli` using project `name`?

Or Is there any workaround to create `issue`, `branch` etc. without using the `id` via `api` or `cli`?

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/39572304/6309 help?

Comment: I think it only works with `api v3`. I tried but not get the desired result.

Comment: You should try this cli tool:  https://github.com/profclems/glab

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [Get single project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-single-project) endpoint. But more generally, you are not limited to using the numerical ID, you can actually use the project name in API calls:

`id`: The ID or [URL-encoded path of the project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#namespaced-path-encoding)

In your particular case, this should work as both an example of getting the ID and to demonstrate that you don't necessarily need the ID :)

```
GET /api/v4/projects/my_namespace%2Fmy_app
```

Comment: But to create `issue` or `branch`, I need `id`. No!!! Or can I use the `my_namespace%2Fmy_app` to create project `issue` or `branch`

Comment: What is the api to create project using `namespace`

Comment: You can use the URL-encoded path of the project to create a new issue: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#new-issue
The same applies for creating a new branch: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#create-repository-branch
The API to create a new project is https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project

Comment: You should try this cli tool: https://github.com/profclems/glab . You can get project issues with `glab issue list`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you read the ID from results of project create call? You can do it easly for example with https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 0):

Use the search API with the projects scope, it is described here:  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/search.html#scope-projects

Answer (score 0):

In Python we have modules which uses the Gitlab APIs to get the details.
You can get the id of the projects using the below python code.Here we are using the gitlab module for making the call.

```
import os
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('http://gitlab_hostname.com', 'your_private_token')
all_projects = gl.projects.list(all=True)
print("All projects id are:",all_projects)
```