# cannot change text to handwriting using pywhatkit

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 2, in <module>
    pywhatkit.text_to_handwriting("""
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pywhatkit\handwriting.py", line 22, in text_to_handwriting
    raise exceptions.UnableToAccessApi("Unable to access Pywhatkit api right now")
pywhatkit.core.exceptions.UnableToAccessApi: Unable to access Pywhatkit api right now

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 2, in <module>
    pywhatkit.text_to_handwriting("""
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pywhatkit\handwriting.py", line 22, in text_to_handwriting
    raise exceptions.UnableToAccessApi("Unable to access Pywhatkit api right now")
pywhatkit.core.exceptions.UnableToAccessApi: Unable to access Pywhatkit api right now
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone reported this issue on [Github](https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit/issues/249). The maintainers aren't hosting the API on Heroku (or anywhere else) at the moment.

They've made their source code for the API function available [here](https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/pywhatkit.herokuapp.com/blob/3025a13b6782e62689d3066bcd3cfc4276c07de3/app.py#L52-L94) though.

I've extracted the `text_to_handwriting` function below:

```
import urllib.request
import string
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2

char = string.ascii_lowercase
file_code_name = {}

width = 50
height = 0
newwidth = 0
arr = string.ascii_letters
arr = arr + string.digits + "+,.-? "
letss = string.ascii_letters


def getimg(case, col):
    global width, height, back
    try:
        url = (
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ankit404butfound/HomeworkMachine/master/Image/%s.png"
            % case
        )
        imglink = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    except:
        url = (
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ankit404butfound/HomeworkMachine/master/Image/%s.PNG"
            % case
        )
        imglink = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    imgNp = np.array(bytearray(imglink.read()))
    img = cv2.imdecode(imgNp, -1)
    cv2.imwrite(r"%s.png" % case, img)
    img = cv2.imread("%s.png" % case)
    img[np.where((img != [255, 255, 255]).all(axis=2))] = col
    cv2.imwrite("chr.png", img)
    cases = Image.open("chr.png")
    back.paste(cases, (width, height))
    newwidth = cases.width
    width = width + newwidth


def text_to_handwriting(string, rgb=[0, 0, 138], save_to: str = "pywhatkit.png"):
    """Convert the texts passed into handwritten characters"""
    global arr, width, height, back
    try:
        back = Image.open("zback.png")
    except:
        url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ankit404butfound/HomeworkMachine/master/Image/zback.png"
        imglink = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        imgNp = np.array(bytearray(imglink.read()))
        img = cv2.imdecode(imgNp, -1)
        cv2.imwrite("zback.png", img)
        back = Image.open("zback.png")
    rgb = [rgb[2], rgb[1], rgb[0]]
    count = -1
    lst = string.split()
    for letter in string:
        if width + 150 >= back.width or ord(letter) == 10:
            height = height + 227
            width = 50
        if letter in arr:
            if letter == " ":
                count += 1
                letter = "zspace"
                wrdlen = len(lst[count + 1])
                if wrdlen * 110 >= back.width - width:
                    width = 50
                    height = height + 227

            elif letter.isupper():
                letter = "c" + letter.lower()
            elif letter == ",":
                letter = "coma"
            elif letter == ".":
                letter = "fs"
            elif letter == "?":
                letter = "que"

            getimg(letter, rgb)

    back.save(f"{save_to}")
    back.close()
    back = Image.open("zback.png")
    width = 50
    height = 0
    return save_to


text_to_handwriting("hello, world!", save_to="myimage.png")
```

Comment: @DavidMakogon code would've been useful, but it's clear from the traceback what function they called.

Comment: Good point on the link-only answer. I'll add the code from the link to the answer. There are lots of API-related questions on SO with high scores, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559689/where-do-i-find-the-project-id-for-the-gitlab-api) - so this question is within the scope of SO in my view. Definitely not a well-formed or thorough one, but still not off-topic.